# Image slider with different image widths slide

Tags: image, slider

I have a div width lets say width:900px; height:300px; overflow:hidden;
Into the div there are some images with height:300px and different widths and a small right margin/padding of 10px; 
So there will be 2 or more images visible in the holder.
I need 2 buttons which slides the images to the 0 point (left:0;).
So when I press on the next arrow the next image (which can be already be visible for a small part) slides to the left at the 0 point.

I can't find any sliders which works like that :(

---

EDIT FOUND IT!

http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php